# Usage of function that use "dill" across multiple modules

Tags: python-3.4, pickle, dill

I hope u can help find a way to solve this 'mistery'.

So I have a python module where inside a class I made a method that uses dill.dump and dill.load_session.I call this method inside the module and it works fine. 
But I have another module, other class, where I import the object from the first module and try to call the method inside this class and nothing happens with dill, not working.
Here is a quick sample of code:

Module A.py

```
import dill
class A(object):
       def __init__(self): pass
       def check():
            temp_file = 'file.pkl'
            dill.load_session(temp_file)
            variable_current = 10
            if variable_current != variable_from_temp_file:
                  variable_from_temp_file = variable_current
                  with open(temp_file,'wb') as pickle_file:
                       dill.dump(variable_from_temp_file,pickle_file)
            return 1
```

Module B.py

```
import A
obj = A()
class B(object):
       def __init__(self): pass
       def create():
            flag = obj.check()
            if flag:
               do something...
object = B()
object.create()
```

When I run B.py it raise the following error:

```
NameError: name 'variable_from_temp_file' is not defined
```

Any solution to this behaviour? Thanks

Comment: Your code can't be executed as is... there are a few errors that need to be corrected.  Without that (and/or some explanation), it's hard to tell what you want to do, so it's hard to help you solve your issue.  Please provide test code that demonstrates your issue.  Also, note that `dump` and `load` are function compliments, and similarly are `dump_session` and `load_session`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I already solved it. The problem was from mixing **load_session** with **dump**.

Comment: As you can see from my comment -- that's what I was hinting at.  You should answer your own question below.